# Why PHP fetch mysqli_fetch_array function return T_Variable error?

Tags: php

I am trying to retrive information from the database table but it gives the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$Row' (T_VARIABLE) in

**The code is:**

```
require_once('../connect.php');
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$query = "SELECT * FROM students_name";            
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

print ("Student Information Table");
print("<table");
print("<tr>");
print("<td><b>No</b></td>");
print("<td><b>First Name</b></td>");
print("<td><b>Last Name</b></td>");
print("<td><b>Adreess</b></td>");
print("<td><b>Course</b></td>");
print("<td><b>Age</b></td>");
print("</tr>");

//result form the data base
while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)){
    print("<tr>");
    print("<td>"$Row[id]"</td>");
    print("<td>"$Row[first_name]"</td>");
    print("<td>"$Row[last_name]"</td>");
    print("<td>"$Row[address]"</td>");
    print("<td>"$Row[course]"</td>");
    print("<td>"$Row[age]"</td>");
    print ("</tr>");
}

mysqli_close ($dbc);
print("</table>");
```

The error line:

```
print("<td>"$Row[id]"</td>");
```

I don't see any syntax error but still doesn't work.

Comment: You're missing the concatenation operator in all of your print statements

Comment: you missed quotes `around array indexes.` example `$Row[id]` MUST BE `$Row['id']` AND SO ON............. also lot of `print` while only few `echo` will work for you

Comment: this `print("<table");` also is incomplete and will break your entire table.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks. It helped.

Comment: @MaihanNijat you're welcome.

Comment: @Anant Thanks. It works.

Comment: Try this:-  `echo "Student Information Table";
echo "<table><tr><td><b>No</b></td><td><b>First Name</b></td><td><b>Last Name</b></td><td><b>Adreess</b></td><td><b>Course</b></td><td><b>Age</b></td></tr>";

//result form the data base
while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)){
    echo"<tr><td>".$Row['id']."</td><td>".$Row['first_name']."</td><td>".$Row['last_name']."</td><td>".$Row['address']."</td><td>".$Row['course']."</td><td>".$Row['age']."</td></tr>";
}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see a syntax error, but it's there...

```
print("<td>".$Row['id']."</td>");
print("<td>".$Row['first_name']."</td>");
print("<td>".$Row['last_name']."</td>");
print("<td>".$Row['address']."</td>");
print("<td>".$Row['course']."</td>");
print("<td>".$Row['age']."</td>");
```

Thanks to @Fred-ii- for pointing this out. You misspelled the table tag:

```
print("<table>"); // was just "<table"
```

Even though it doesn't cause the error, it will mess your table up.

Which in HTML source or HTML debugger would throw the following:

> Stray start tag "td"

in regards to the missing `>` for `print("<table");`

Comment: [*You missed this...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685763/why-php-fetch-mysqli-fetch-array-function-return-t-variable-error#comment59048968_35685763) ;-)

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I am going to tick it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanx for pointing this out, but technically this doesn't cause the T_VARIABLE error :))

Comment: @Nordenheim I never said it would cause the error, I said it would break their table and throw an HTML error in source. *2 different animals altogether* ;-)

Comment: I want to say @Fred-ii- is always correct. and great thing he caught very small mistakes too

Comment: @Anant well... when I recognize obvious errors, yes. I do make mistakes occasionally ;-) nobody is perfect. HTML markup I know quite well though. 20+ years.

Comment: `I do make mistakes occasionally` :) may be, till now i didn't see anyone from you. I really appreciate your help to me too in my posts ,comments and answers.